# Intransit through IAH

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I am flying from Tokyo to Houston and will connect same day on a flight to Port of Spain, Trinidad. Previously in Houston there was a one-stop facility for international to international intransit passengers whereby it was not necessary to claim and recheck baggage. Does this still apply?

Comment: No.  You will have to claim your bags, enter the United States, then recheck your bags, then pass through TSA to enter the terminal.

Comment: According to [this page](http://www.fly2houston.com/iah/international-travel/) there is a OneStop shortcut after immigration (before customs) IF you have carry-on luggage only.

Comment: I've never done it, but I've seen scattered reports that, in theory (and [sometimes it fails miserably](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/united-airlines-mileageplus/1574402-warning-problems-international-transit-bags-iah.html)), United Airlines (and only United Airlines) can tag your bags with a green "T" tag for international-to-international transfers so you don't have to claim and recheck luggage. This is mentioned, vaguely, [on the IAH website under OneStop](http://www.fly2houston.com/iah/international-travel/).

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that after the immigration at IAH, you must pick up your bags, go through a small customs checkpoint, then recheck them immediately after the customs stand. It is very simple and quick (as they simply scan your baggage tag and put your bags on a conveyor belt) - and then you can proceed through the security checkpoint upstairs.